# How to allow duplicate row names in R data.frame during Bootstrap Resampling with replacement?

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 dataframes for comparison that are all linked by row.names (genotype, kinship, phenotype).

In order to perform Bootstrap resampling, I would like to take multiple samples from my phenotype file and allow for replacement -- this necessitates allowing for duplicate row.names so that all files will match up.

Neither `check.rows = F` nor `check.names = F` is allowing duplicates.

---

`phenoperm = data.frame(pheno[sample(nrow(pheno), replace = TRUE), ], check.rows = F, check.names = F)`

---

which produces altered row.names for the replicates:

---

`X1`

`X1.1`

`X1.2`

---

When I try to force the row.names: `rownames(phenoperm) <- phenoperm$rownames` I get this error:

`Error in`*row.names<-.data.frame*`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘X1’`

Any help is much appreciated!

More code:

```
for(p in 1:perms) {print(p)

                    ### THE LINE BELOW DOES NOT ALLOW FOR DUPLICATE ROW.NAMES ###
                    ### DUPLICATE ROW.NAMES ARE NECESSARY TO MATCH OTHER FILES ###

                    phenoperm = data.frame(pheno[sample(nrow(pheno), replace = TRUE), ], row.names = phenoperm$row.names, check.names = FALSE, check.rows = FALSE)

                    ### INSTEAD IT PRODUCES DUPLICATE ROW.NAMES AS 23, 23.1, 23.2, ETC ###
                    ### THE NUMBERS IN WHICH A "-.1" OR ".2" ARE ADDED DO NOT MATCH ###


                    result = GRSDbinom.permsfast(data[[chr]], pheno = phenoperm, pheno.col = "pheno.col", addcovar, tx, sanger.dir)
                    top <- max(-log10(result$pv))
                    MAX.LOD = result$POS[which(-log10(result$pv) >= top)]

                    # Save the locus.
                    permutations[p,] = c(min(MAX.LOD), max(MAX.LOD))
            }
```

Comment: Could you gives us more details by adding some more codes. You don't necessarily need row names. But with information you provided It's difficult to tell you more

Comment: I have the same problem when I use a **matrix**, they also will not allow duplicate row.names and rename them.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to add, DJJ, the codes are very long and utilize the glm() -- this is where matching by row.name is necessitated.  I am just hoping to find a way to allow for duplicate row.names in a data.frame or a matrix (both rename in my hands).  It seems that the literature indicates that this is exactly the reason "check.rows = F" exists, but it does not work here.  Perhaps becuase the line contains subsetting?  It seems like such a simple problem, but I have been at it for over a day now!

Comment: How about reading the files in with row.names=F so that genotype, kinship and phenotype are in a column for merging

Comment: The code to do bootstrapping should not be "very long" at least if you use the `boot` package which has "recommended" status. I suggest you are not doing it efficiently. I agree with DJJ that we are not likely to be able to provide a tested solution until the is sufficient detail to begin coding. The `glm` function does not do matching, and you make reference to a "line that does subsetting" is rather vague.

Comment: ok, I will post more, but still the only goal I have is to allow for duplicate row.names in either a data.frame or matrix

Comment: For anyone who runs across this problem and is looking for an answer, this may be helpful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

"In R, row names must be unique, so combining coefficients from many models (e.g., from bootstrap resamples, or subgroups) requires workarounds to avoid losing important information. This knocks you out of the flow of analysis and makes it harder to combine the results from multiple models. I'm not currently aware of any packages that resolve this problem."